# Limiting the Number of Associated Records in Intermediate Table in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

#### Context

There are two PostgreSQL tables, Table A and Table B.
Each table has an id column as the primary key, and a name column as a string.

Now, I want to create an intermediate table that connects the two tables based on matching values in the name column.

To do so, I can simply execute the following query and it works fine(assume that an empty intermediate_table already exists):

```
INSERT INTO intermediate_table (a_id, b_id)
SELECT a.id, b.id
FROM table_a a
JOIN table_b b ON a.name = b.name
```

#### Problem

I would like to impose a new constraint on this process.
I want to limit the number of Table B records associated with a single record in Table A through the intermediate table to a maximum of 100 records (and vice versa).

Even if a single record in Table A has more than 100 matching records in Table B, only the first 100 records should be inserted into the intermediate table.

For example:

```
Table A has a record with id=1 and name="Adam".
Table A has a record with id=2 and name="Davis".

Table B has records with id=1 to 150, all of which have name="Adam".
Table B has records with id=151 to 200, all of which have name="Davis".

In this case, Table A with id=1 should be associated with Table B records with id=1 to 100, and Table A with id=2 should be associated with Table B records with id=151 to 200. 
Therefore, the intermediate table should contain 150 records.
```

#### What I've tried

```
INSERT INTO intermediate_table (a_id, b_id)
SELECT a.id, b.id
FROM table_a a
JOIN table_b b ON a.name = b.name
LIMIT 100
```

I tried the above SQL query, but it limits the total number of records in the intermediate_table, resulting in only 100 records being created in my example.

### Question

- How can I modify the SQL query to achieve the desired behavior?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See example

```
-- data model
create table table_A (id int generated by default as identity,name varchar(10));
create table table_B (id int generated by default as identity,name varchar(10));
create table intermediate_table (a_id int ,b_id int);
insert into table_A values (1,'Adam'),(2,'Davis');
with recursive dataAdam as(
  select 1 n,'Adam' nm
  union all
  select n+1,nm from dataAdam where (n+1)<=150
)
insert into table_B (id,name)
select n,nm from dataAdam;

with recursive dataDavis as(
  select 151 n,'Davis' nm
  union all
  select n+1,nm from dataDavis where (n+1)<=200
)
insert into table_B (id,name)
select  n,nm from dataDavis

-- query example

INSERT INTO intermediate_table (a_id, b_id)
SELECT a_id, b_id
FROM (
  select a.id as a_id,b.id as b_id 
     ,row_number()over(partition by b.name order by b.id) rn
  from table_a a
  JOIN table_b b ON a.name = b.name
  ) t
where rn<=100;
```

Compact and clearer variant (@Boorusk)

```
-- data model
create table table_A (id int,name varchar(10));
create table table_B (id int,name varchar(10));
create table intermediate_table (a_id int ,b_id int);
insert into table_A values (1,'Adam'),(2,'Davis');

insert into table_B (id,name)
select n,'Adam' From generate_series(1,150) n;

insert into table_B (id,name)
select  n,'Davis' from generate_series(151,200) n

-- query example
INSERT INTO intermediate_table (a_id, b_id)
SELECT a_id, b_id
FROM (
  select a.id as a_id,b.id as b_id 
     ,row_number()over(partition by b.name order by b.id) rn
  from table_a a
  JOIN table_b b ON a.name = b.name
  ) t
where rn<=100;
```

Comment: you can simplify your inserts 
`SELECT id, 'ADAM' FROM generate_series(1, 150) id;`

Comment: @Boorusk, thank you. I was test query in SQL Server previously. Your method is more applicable.